# Why do line breaks stop working with addition of ScrollView?

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview, line-breaks

I am currently working on a project where I need to create a line-break in a TextView. I know how to do this with \n and did so. However, when I wrapped my code in a ScrollView, line breaks don't work no matter what I do. What causes the line breaks to stop working and how do I fix it?

Here is the code:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HeroImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ogre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:text="Fat Ogre Comics"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="roboto"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comics and Tabletop Gaming"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:fontFamily="roboto"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="525 Sawdust Rd. Ste: 101 \nThe Woodlands, 77380 \nPhone:(281) 292-8444"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/fatogreinstore"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="Sunday 11AM–7PM \nMonday 11AM–9PM \nTuesday 11AM–9PM \nWednesday 11AM–9PM \nThursday 11AM–9PM \nFriday 11AM–10PM \nSaturday 10AM–10PM"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The line breaks are in the 3rd and last TextViews.

Comment: You can move the text values to strings.xml, it will work.

Comment: I tried your layout. ScrollView works with line breaks when running but not work in the preview of Android Studio. To fix it, I added, xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools", and the preview becomes normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the preview to work, add: xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"

OR

Connect a phone and it will run just fine.